# How to use webpack with a monorepo (yarnpkg workspaces)

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, yarnpkg

I'm using  [yarn workspaces](https://github.com/thejameskyle/rfcs-1/blob/workspaces/accepted/0000-workspaces.md) where the root directory has a package directory with all my repos. Each repo has its own node_modules directory containing its dependencies.  The root node_modules directory contains all the dev dependencies for the whole project as well as all other dev related things such as webpack.config files. Webpack uses hot module reload for the express server package.

The problem I have is, how to configure webpack externals to exclude all node_modules directories through the whole project, not just in the root?

[webpack-node-externals](https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals) doesn't seem to work given this scenario.

Error message:

```
WARNING in ./packages/servers/express/node_modules/colors/lib/colors.js
127:29-43 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./packages/servers/express/node_modules/express/lib/view.js
79:29-41 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

Webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const StartServerPlugin = require('start-server-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    'webpack/hot/poll?1000',
    path.join(__dirname, '../packages/servers/express/server/index.js')
  ],
  watch: true,
  target: 'node',
  externals: [
    nodeExternals({
      whitelist: ['webpack/hot/poll?1000']
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      handlebars: 'handlebars/dist/handlebars.js'
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new StartServerPlugin('server.js'),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': { BUILD_TARGET: JSON.stringify('server') }
    })
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../packages/servers/express/.build'),
    filename: 'server.js'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 24):

If using yarn workspaces with `webpack-node-externals` a better solution than setting `modulesFromFile: true` is to use the following `externals` setting in your webpack config:

```
externals: [
  nodeExternals(),
  nodeExternals({
    modulesDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/root/node_modules'),
  }),
],
```

Essentially using two instances of nodeExternals. 1 for the package `node_modules` and one for the root `node_modules`.

Comment: I tried both ways and this way was about 1 second faster on the build time (I'm using a really weak chromebook).  I'm not sure what the `moduleFromFiles` does but at least with my very limited testing, this solution is faster.

Comment: You saved my life after hunting this for 9 hours... I did not need the first `nodeExternals()` though

Comment: If I get it right, the first `nodeExternal()` will only remove packages found in local node_modules, so mostly nothing in the context of Yarn workspaces. The second one will remove the root node_modules too.

Comment: Found the pattern to put that in a common webpack config: `externals: [ nodeExternals({  additionalModuleDirs: [path.resolve(__dirname, path/to/root/node_modules")] }) ]`. It's works similarly to your answer but additionalModuleDirs is more concise.

Comment: Link: https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals/issues/39#issuecomment-655743743

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to @blackxored I was able to fix it on my project.

In your webpack config file do the following:

```
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals'
```

Then add

```
externals: [
  nodeExternals({
    modulesFromFile: true,
  }),
],
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate the consequences of this? If I get it right, as a default nodeExternals will exclude anything that it found both in the root node_modules and in your code. With this option however, you force him to read your local package.json instead. Am I right?

Answer (score 5):

Yarn workspaces hoist compatible modules to the root node_modules directory leaving any incompatible (different semver, etc.) modules with the dependent workspace's node_modules directory. If a package is requested without using a relative path it is either native, from node_module's, or possibly a symlinked package from one of your workspaces. You probably want all of those packages to be external.

> how to configure webpack externals to exclude all node_modules directories through the whole project, not just in the root?

I would try [using a function with webpack's external option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#function). You are passed the context of the require, the name of the module requested, and a callback to indicate whether this particular import (require) should be considered external.

```
externals: [
    (ctx, req, cb) => {
        if (!/node_modules/.test(ctx) && req[0] !== '.') {
            // Assumes you have defined an "entries" variable
            let notAnEntry = (path) => {
                return Object.keys(entries).every((entry) => {
                    return entries[entry] !== path
                });
            };

            if (notAnEntry(require.resolve(req))) {
                // This module is external in a commonjs context
                return cb(null, `commonjs ${req}`);
            }
        }

        cb();
    }
]
```