# Typescript definition not refreshed in watch mode while using workspace

Tags: typescript, webpack, single-page-application, micro-frontend, yarn-workspaces

Hello all and thank you for reading me,

I have made a react micro-frontend project out of spa v5.9, webpack v5.75, babel-loader v9.1, ts-loader v9.4 and yarn workspace v3.5. I have only very basic content to bootstrap the project structure:

- root spa => package root
- application spa => package app1
- utils spa => package utils1
- react lib utils spa => package utils2

My current issue is that, when running the app on webpack dev, if I add a new function to utils1 and then try to use it in app1, I always have a typescript error saying there is no existing export for this function.

Of course, the application is running well, so it is (I guess) a pure misconfiguration of webpack, loaders and/or typescript. Unfortunately I am not an expert in this kind of config, and I did not find on stackoverflow nor github repos that could help to solve it :(

For more details on the configuration used, you can find my project here [single-spa-typescript-yarn-worspace](https://github.com/MathieuVedana/single-spa-typescript-yarn-worspace)

My question is : how can I resolve the typescript error when using webpack?

I believe that my repo will help many people like me having troubles to bootstrap this kind of project structure. So that would be great to share the solution :)

Something interesting is that the updated d.ts files of utils1 are well created in my dist directory by ts-loader and emitted in app1 as `assets by path ../../utils1`. But seems not enough.

Logs from console when adding new function

```
[@mma/utils1]: assets by path *.js 257 KiB
[@mma/utils1]:   asset mma-utils1.js 256 KiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
[@mma/utils1]:   asset main.7298c5f52c40300d30e4.hot-update.js 1.17 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [hmr] (name: main) 1 related asset
[@mma/utils1]: asset index.html 3.05 KiB [emitted]
[@mma/utils1]: asset main.7298c5f52c40300d30e4.hot-update.json 28 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]
[@mma/utils1]: Entrypoint main 257 KiB (288 KiB) = mma-utils1.js 256 KiB main.7298c5f52c40300d30e4.hot-update.js 1.17 KiB 2 auxiliary assets
[@mma/utils1]: cached modules 177 KiB [cached] 29 modules
[@mma/utils1]: runtime modules 26.3 KiB 12 modules
[@mma/utils1]: ./src/mma-utils1.ts 278 bytes [built] [code generated]
[@mma/utils1]: webpack 5.78.0 compiled successfully in 120 ms
[@mma/utils1]: No issues found.
[@mma/app1]: <i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /mma-app1.js
[@mma/app1]: assets by path ../../utils1/ 16.3 KiB
[@mma/app1]:   asset ../../utils1/tsconfig.tsbuildinfo 15.9 KiB [emitted]
[@mma/app1]:   asset ../../utils1/dist/mma-utils1.d.ts.map 222 bytes [emitted]
[@mma/app1]:   asset ../../utils1/dist/mma-utils1.d.ts 213 bytes [emitted]
[@mma/app1]: assets by path *.js 311 KiB
[@mma/app1]:   asset mma-app1.js 311 KiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
[@mma/app1]:   asset main.e16099d5ac744012f09a.hot-update.js 349 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr] (name: main) 1 related asset
[@mma/app1]: asset index.html 3.04 KiB [emitted]
[@mma/app1]: asset main.e16099d5ac744012f09a.hot-update.json 28 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]
[@mma/app1]: Entrypoint main 311 KiB (346 KiB) = mma-app1.js 311 KiB main.e16099d5ac744012f09a.hot-update.js 349 bytes 2 auxiliary assets
[@mma/app1]: cached modules 223 KiB [cached] 37 modules
[@mma/app1]: runtime modules 26.3 KiB 12 modules
[@mma/app1]: javascript modules 1.39 KiB
[@mma/app1]:   ./src/mma-app1.tsx 619 bytes [built]
[@mma/app1]:   ./src/root.component.tsx 800 bytes [built]
[@mma/app1]: webpack 5.78.0 compiled successfully in 713 ms
[@mma/app1]: No issues found.
```

Log when trying to use that function

```
[@mma/app1]: assets by path *.js 313 KiB
[@mma/app1]:   asset mma-app1.js 311 KiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
[@mma/app1]:   asset main.a4f5012940d30ef822c1.hot-update.js 2.34 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [hmr] (name: main) 1 related asset
[@mma/app1]: asset index.html 3.04 KiB [emitted]
[@mma/app1]: asset main.a4f5012940d30ef822c1.hot-update.json 28 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]
[@mma/app1]: Entrypoint main 313 KiB (347 KiB) = mma-app1.js 311 KiB main.a4f5012940d30ef822c1.hot-update.js 2.34 KiB 2 auxiliary assets
[@mma/app1]: cached modules 224 KiB [cached] 38 modules
[@mma/app1]: runtime modules 26.3 KiB 12 modules
[@mma/app1]: ./src/root.component.tsx 800 bytes [built] [code generated]
[@mma/app1]: webpack 5.78.0 compiled successfully in 268 ms
[@mma/app1]: ERROR in src/root.component.tsx:1:10
[@mma/app1]: TS2305: Module '"@mma/utils1"' has no exported member 'newFunction'.
[@mma/app1]:   > 1 | import { newFunction, toLowerCaseText } from "@mma/utils1";
[@mma/app1]:       |          ^^^^^^^^^^^
[@mma/app1]:     2 | import { toUpperCaseText } from "@mma/utils1";
[@mma/app1]:     3 | import { HelloComponent } from "@mma/utils2";
[@mma/app1]:     4 |
```

Comment: Posting as a comment rather than an answer because I don't have time to test this, but since you're in a monorepo, and it looks like `@mma/utils` is coming from the workspace, you may need to use something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-watch-files-plugin) to get Webpack to actually pick up all the changes. Other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46010926/how-to-use-webpack-with-a-monorepo-yarnpkg-workspaces) might also be helpful.

Comment: Hello @ZacAnger, 
Ty for your answer :)
I think that [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46010926/how-to-use-webpack-with-a-monorepo-yarnpkg-workspaces) is too old to be taken in account, the ecosystem ahs changes so much in 5 years.
Using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-watch-files-plugin) (webpack watch plugin), I may have a test, however it seems to be a specific workaround than a real explanation/solution.

Comment: Seems many people just want to ignore typescript errors from webpack!? May be I shall do the same as everything else is just working fine...

Answer (score 0):

I think I have kind use my brain wisely today, I have I think a good level of configuration that works as a charm when running with webpack.

As I was expecting that the config issue was from fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin embedded by webpack-config-single-spa-ts v4.1.3, I decided to look deeper in its configuration and I figure it out that its embedded configuration was wrong against documentation.
Its current conf is :

```
          new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
            typescript: {
              mode: "write-references",
            },
          }),
```

As per [fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin doc](https://github.com/TypeStrong/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin#typescript-options), if `mode: "write-references"` then we need `build: true`. After a few search, I realized that using build mode of tsc will compile also our reference project however we do not need to have written files, in-memory is enough. I replace the configuration like this:

```
      new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
        typescript: {
          mode: "readonly", // Assuming that your production build use tsc
          build: true, // This enables your app to build also dependencies (references), otherwise you will have typescript errors because your project won't be aware of your reference project
        },
      }),
```

That work exactly as I expect, while app run under webpack dev:

- if I change `utils1` project method name used by `app1`, it will raise a legit typescript error :)
- if I add a function to `utils1` and then call it from `app1`, it will not complain of unknown export from `utils1` :)

This configuration only applies pacakges that are uses references in tsconfig, in my case,not to root app nor utils.

I have also tweaked configuration for my spa utils, by emptying the config and leaving the default as my utils don't rely on other packages. This will lead to in-memory files:

```
new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({}), // Overrides the conf mode: "write-references" from singleSpaDefaults. We use in-memory readonly definition, assuming you run your production build with tsc.
```

All my changes are available in [develop branch of my repo](https://github.com/MathieuVedana/single-spa-typescript-yarn-worspace/tree/develop).

For those who want to follow my repo, I will try to add fast-refresh and css prefix by package in next commits and may be other features.

Don't hesitate to open discussions/issues if you have other ideas to add to that repo :)

Previous investigation state:

> Well well,  I think I have narrowed the origin of these error messages
> from plugin fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin. If I remove it from
> webpack conf as bellow function in app1 webpack conf, then the errors
> are no more showing-up.
>
> I was working on that idea because fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin is
> running in another process, so kind of asynchronous issue between the
> plugin and webpack?
>
> Not 100% sure if by doing this
>
> - I have fully deactivated typescript check
> - Or if I have just avoided typescript type check issue because removing it has given the role to do typecheck to only ts-loader.
>
> What do you think?
>
> I will investigate a bit more about the side effects.
>
> Update available in that [branch on my
> repo](https://github.com/MathieuVedana/single-spa-typescript-yarn-worspace/tree/remove-ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin)